# SMF forum login for iPhone

Tags: iphone, authentication, smf

I've google quite a lot but I can't find an example or tutorial, so guys can you help me think of a code which would log in smf forum?

My guess is that I should use ASIIHTTPRequest?

Comment: simple machines forum
www.simplemachines.org

Answer (score 0):

```
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request;

//login to SMF - this works
request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://imtgapp.com/forum/index.php?action=login2"]];
[request setPostValue: @"test" forKey: @"user"];
[request setPostValue: @"12345" forKey: @"passwrd"];
[request setPostValue: @"1" forKey: @"cookieneverexp"];
[request setPostValue: @"" forKey: @"hash_passwrd"]; //TODO ?

[request setValidatesSecureCertificate: NO];

[request setCompletionBlock: ^{
    //TODO verify if login was successful
    NSLog( @"%@", [request responseString] );

}];

[request setFailedBlock: ^{
    NSLog( @"Unresolved error %@, %@", [request error], [[request error] userInfo] );
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SSI feature: http://simplemachines.org/community/ssi_examples.php

```
<?php
require("SSI.php");
// Shows a login box only when user is not logged in
ssi_login();
?>
```

...